# Is "Smilemall" a scam?

Tags: websites, scam

I found a very good deal (almost everything else on the site has a normal price) on `acsung.top` and was initially pretty interested but there are some things that make me question if I can trust this vendor:

- I can find almost nothing about acsung or Smilemall online
- Why would a company called Smilemall have the domain acsung.top?
- Some of the links on their website are broken
- When you go to checkout, there is a spot for coupon codes but, similar to the website, I can not find anything about these coupons anywhere
- The email at the bottom of the page is x24@vipserver.vip which:
  a) does not seem very professional,
  b) uses a domain I have never seen before,
  c) does not exist to an email checker website,
  d) according to emailHippo, the email is unverifiable with a trust score of 3, uses cloudflare (which my brother says is "very sus")
- According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.top#:%7E:text=A%20second%20level%20domain%20under,of%2010%20years%20in%20advance.), .top domains are often used for malware and phishing, and the TLD is included in the list of those banned for some antimalware vendors such as Malwarebytes

---

While writing this, I realized it seems very likely that this is a scam and my evidence points pretty conclusively that this website is a scam. However, I am nowhere near a professional and this is my first time looking into website security so a second opinion would be reassuring.

---

After another look, it looks like there are a lot of crazy deals

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't review sites to determine if they are a "scam"